# Androidчтение из .txt

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! 
Пытаюсь считать  текст из .txt, перебрал интернет, но не выходит.
В IDEA проблем не было - закинул в директорию, считал - все работает.
Пытаюсь выводит и весь лист RFF и  отдельные элементы - эффект = NULL.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где я не прав и как исправить?

```
ArrayList<String> RFF;
    public void REad(){
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
            InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("C:\\Android\\app\\TestWord\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\anagramlist.txt"));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(istream);
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                    this.RFF.add(str);
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Файл на компьютере? А считать надо телефоном/эмулятором? Это как?

Comment: Может я чего не понимаю, пардон, но считываться должен текст не с телефона или карты памяти, он является частью кода

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что в андроиде код исполняется в эмуляторе андроида и там нет никаких C:/Android итд.

Comment: Тогда я что-то совсем запутался, в idea было с этим все понятней. Как в таком случае я могу из файла подтягивать текст в код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай папку Assets - меню File | New | Folder | Assets Folder.
Положи туда файл.
При считывании указывай только имя файла, без пути.